# Pandas Explode on Multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-explode

Using Pandas 0.25.3, trying to explode a couple of columns.

Data looks like:

```py
d1 = {'user':['user1','user2','user3','user4'],
      'paid':['Y','Y','N','N']
      'last_active':['11 Jul 2019','23 Sep 2018','08 Dec 2019','03 Mar 2018'],
      'col4':'data'}
```

I sent this to a dataframe `df=pd.DataFrame([d1],columns=d1.keys())` that looks like this:

```py
user                              paid              last_active                                                col4               
['user1','user2','user3','user4'] ['Y','Y','N','N'] ['11 Jul 2019','23 Sep 2018','08 Dec 2019','03 Mar 2018']  'data'
```

there are other columns as well with one value per, `{'A':'B'}` type stuff, but I'm not worried about those.

when I do `df.explode('user')` it works for that one, and same for the other columns, but when I try to do `df.explode(column=('user','paid','last_active')` it gives me the following error:

`KeyError: ('user','paid','last_active')`

So what I want to know, is how can I explode it with the `explode` function on multiple columns to get the following df:

```py
user     paid  last_active    col4
'user1'  'Y'   '11 Jul 2019'  'data'
'user2'  'Y'   '23 Sep 2018'  NaN
'user3'  'N'   '08 Dec 2019'  NaN
'user4'  'N'   '03 Mar 2018'  NaN
```

Comment: just do `df=pd.DataFrame(d1)`., without `[]`

Comment: it gives me an error on account of the arrays are not the same length (col4 has 1 element in it, the others have multiple)

Comment: @QuangHoang that would give you a row having `data` for each row (not only the first row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need (note the difference in data for `col4` which has `None` as OP mentioned):

```
pd.DataFrame([[i] if not isinstance(i,list) else i 
             for i in d1.values()],index=d1.keys()).T
```

---

```
    user paid  last_active  col4
0  user1    Y  11 Jul 2019  data
1  user2    Y  23 Sep 2018  None
2  user3    N  08 Dec 2019  None
3  user4    N  03 Mar 2018  None
```

Comment: @anky_91 nice one! +1

Comment: @anky what about if I have a dataframe, no dictionary, how could I modify your above code to get the same result directly from exploding a dataframe or applying the above code to my dataframe?  This works great for my test dictionary issue, but my data is in a df and even changing it to_dict() causes it to not be in the correct format to apply your above code.

Answer (score 6):

Pandas does not have a multi-column explode. There are workarounds. One such simple way could be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [1, 2],
        'B': [['a','b'], ['c','d']],
        'C': [['z','y'], ['x','w']]
    }
)
print(df)

--------------
A    B     C
--------------
1 [a, b] [z, y]
2 [c, d] [x, w]

##Let us say list_cols are the columns to be exploded
list_cols = {'B','C'}

other_cols = list(set(df.columns) - set(list_cols))
##other_cols now contains all the remaining column names in the df
##we temporarily convert to set() to easily get the differences in 2 lists

##now explode the list_cols using a loop
exploded = [df[col].explode() for col in list_cols]
##now we have long list of exploded values. Print to see the format

##This statement creates pairs of the exploded cols
##zip command is used to create the pairs
##dict puts it in an appropriate format from which a dataframe can be created
##Please print the individual outputs of each command to understand the flow
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list_cols, exploded)))

##Now merge back the other_cols as well
df2 = df[other_cols].merge(df2, how="right", left_index=True, right_index=True)

##lastly, re-create the original column order
df2 = df2.loc[:, df.columns]

print(df2)

------
A B C
------
1 a z
1 b y
2 c x
2 d w
```

Comment: I applied this logic but every time the B and C columns are getting interchanged.

Comment: the above code should work. Please share your code to check what is going wrong

Comment: Please could you add some more step-by-step description to your code. It is hard do understand what happens here.

Comment: I have added a few comments inline