# Explode multiple coumns with different size list columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following situation where i may get 300 columns in csv file and some of them are list parameter (50 columns)and they can uneven size including no values.

```
    Time               COL1                        COL2
2020-03-13 10:43:00.500  0.0 10.0 20.0 30.0 40.0   50.0 60.0 70.0 80.0 90.0
2020-03-13 10:43:00.900  10.0 20.0 30.0 70.0       10.0 20.0
2020-03-13 10:44:00.100  10.0 20.0 30.0 70.0
```

I want do
1. explode the column based on highest frequency to rows.ex: 1st row max freq(space separated values) 
    is 5 and in 2nd row it is 4

```
Time                  COL1      COL2
2020-03-13 10:43:00.500   0.0    50.0
2020-03-13 10:43:00.580   10.0   60.0
2020-03-13 10:43:00.660   20.0   70.0
2020-03-13 10:43:00.740   30.0   80.0
2020-03-13 10:43:00.820   40.0   90.0    
2020-03-13 10:43:00.900   10.0   10.0 
2020-03-13 10:43:00.1150  20.0   20.0 
2020-03-13 10:43:00.1400  30.0 
2020-03-13 10:43:00.1650  80.0 
2020-03-13 10:44:00.100   10.0 
2020-03-13 10:44:00.350   20.0 
2020-03-13 10:44:00.600   30.0
2020-03-13 10:44:00.850   70.0
```

2. and Time filed should be between two subsequent row time. 
   something like this.

   curr_row_time = data_frame['Time'][ind1]
   next_row_time = data_frame['Time'][ind1+1]
   timestamp1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(curr_row_time ),
                                               '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
   timestamp2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(next_row_time),
                                               '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
   time_delta = (timestamp2 - timestamp1).total_seconds() * 1000
   time_step_increment = time_delta / max_frequency (should be max for a row)
   for last row max frequency can be taken either avg of it or last used max frequency
   Appreciate if any suggestion for point 1 however 2nd point is on second priority but its good to have that also.

For point 1 i have used below

I tried solution mentioned in the below links by converting space separated to  list
10.0 20.0 30.0 70.0   ----> [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 70.0] 
[Pandas Explode on Multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59377817/pandas-explode-on-multiple-columns)

```
 File "<stdin>", line 3, in <listcomp>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Below links works for equal size list column
[Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Comment: you time data doesn't look standard (missing hour maybe?). Aso, I'm not entirely sure about the time interpolation in the last 4 rows.

Comment: @QuangHoang Its typo i will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can create the exploded columns like you want with `concat`, `str.split` and `stack`. Use `reset_index` and `join` to be able to get the column 'Time' associated. Then you need to change the values in the column 'Time' to create the interpolation. I'm not sure if one can interpolate directly a datetime column, but you can change the type to `int64`, `mask` the values if same than previous row with `shift` and `interpolate`. So like this:

```
l_col = ['COL1', 'COL2']

df_f = pd.concat([df[col].str.split(' ', expand=True) for col in l_col ], 
                 axis=1, keys=l_col)\
         .stack()\
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)\
         .join(df[['Time']])\
         .reset_index(drop=True)

df_f['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_f['Time'].astype('int64')
                                          .mask(df_f.Time.eq(df_f.Time.shift()))
                                          .interpolate(method='linear'))

print (df_f)
    COL1  COL2                    Time
0    0.0  50.0 2020-03-13 10:43:00.500
1   10.0  60.0 2020-03-13 10:43:00.580
2   20.0  70.0 2020-03-13 10:43:00.660
3   30.0  80.0 2020-03-13 10:43:00.740
4   40.0  90.0 2020-03-13 10:43:00.820
5   10.0  10.0 2020-03-13 10:43:00.900
6   20.0  20.0 2020-03-13 10:43:15.700
7   30.0  None 2020-03-13 10:43:30.500
8   70.0  None 2020-03-13 10:43:45.300
9   10.0       2020-03-13 10:44:00.100
10  20.0  None 2020-03-13 10:44:00.100
11  30.0  None 2020-03-13 10:44:00.100
12  70.0  None 2020-03-13 10:44:00.100
```

I'm not sure what you want for the missing values in COL2 e.g. so you may need some `fillna` to work this out.